# Convert a IList<int> collection to a comma separated list

Tags: c#, ilist

Any elegant ways of converting a IList collection to a string of comma separated id's?

"1,234,2,324,324,2"

Comment: Isn't this close enough to your other question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
    IList<int> list = new List<int>( new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } );
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list));
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  ForEach() is defined on List<T>, not IList<T>.

Comment: No need to call `ToArray`. The `string.Join` overload used operates on `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Yep, fixed. Can't recall why I had that in there 9 years ago.

Comment: @EdS. That overload was added in .NET 4.0, which came out two weeks after you wrote this answer.  There's also a generic overload now, so there's no need for the `Select` either, you can just pass in an `IEnumerable<T>` (in this case, of ints) and it'll get the string value of each one for you.  (That overload was also added at the same time.)

Comment: @Servy: That makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
// Given: IList<int> collection;

string commaSeparatedInts = string.Join(",",collection.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do it

```
IList<int> strings = new List<int>(new int[] { 1,2,3,4 });
string[] myStrings = strings.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();
string joined = string.Join(",", myStrings);
```

OR entirely with Linq

```
string aggr = strings.Select(s=> s.ToString()).Aggregate((agg, item) => agg + "," + item);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// list = IList<MyObject>

var strBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

foreach(var obj in list)
{
  strBuilder.Append(obj.ToString());
  strBuilder.Append(",");
}

strBuilder = strBuilder.SubString(0, strBuilder.Length -1);
return strBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: A good choice, I've always found StringBuilder to be a much faster at concatenation. Especially useful if the size of the list is BIG!

Comment: StringBuilder.SubString doesn't exist, what you want is StringBuilder.ToString(int startIndex, int length)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>{1,234,2,324,324,2};
var str = intList.Select(i => i.ToString()).Aggregate( (i1,i2) => string.Format("{0},{1}",i1,i2));
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if the person down voting an answer would leave a comment as to why it was down voted.
This is a perfectly legitimate solution to the problem!

Comment: Yes, legitimate, just not the most simple way to do it.  The ranking system is simply about getting the best answers to the top.

Comment: I would imagine that an answer would get down voted only if it is either incorrect, inaccurate or lacks details. Most of the answers posted here using LINQ are not necessarily "simple"!

Comment: I agree with you Abhijeet.  Voting up is for ranking.  Voting down is for incorrect.  I set you back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

mstrickland has a good idea on using string builder because of its speed with larger lists. However, you can't set a stringbuilder as a string. Try this instead.

```
    var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var obj in list)
    {
        strBuilder.Append(obj.ToString());
        strBuilder.Append(",");
    }

    return strBuilder.ToString(0, strBuilder.Length - 1);
```